# MS-ACCESS - Before insert/after insert/update trigger required

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2016, ms-access-data-macro

I have a **PropertyOwnership** table which has a **PercentOwnership** field.
Please note that any property can have multiple owners, hence we require the percent ownership for each owner.

When adding a record into the PropertyOwnership table, I would like to insert a trigger that will ensure the correct percentage value is added i.e. when we add all the percent ownership of the property, it should not be greater than 100.

I have tried creating a event driven data macro for after insert/update trigger as followed:

**Macro Name: InvalidOwnership**

```
Parameter 1 name: PropertyNameTemp
Parameter 2 name: PercentOwnershipTemp

SetLocalVar Name: RunningPercent
Expression: 0

lookup each record in PropertyOwnership where PropertyName = PropertyNameTemp
   SetLocalVar Name: RunningPercent
   Expression      : RunningPercent + PercentOwnership

If PercentOwnershipTemp + RunningPercent > 100

RaiseError.
```

---

I use the above data macro within the After insert and update trigger (table event macro) but it doesnt seem to work.

Please assist :)

Comment: Update your tags with correct version of ms-access. And properly describe "it doesn't seem to work"

Answer (score 0):

Use **For Each Record in** block instead of **LookUp Each Record** as it will operate only first record.

When the RunningPercent is greater than 100 it will raise error which can be seen from **Application Log**, however the record will be inserted in table.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DataMacros xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/accessservices/2009/11/application">
   <DataMacro Name="InvalidOwnership">
      <Parameters>
         <Parameter Name="PropertyNameTemp" />
         <Parameter Name="PercentOwnershipTemp" />
      </Parameters>
      <Statements>
         <Action Name="SetLocalVar">
            <Argument Name="Name">RunningPercent</Argument>
            <Argument Name="Value">0</Argument>
         </Action>
         <ForEachRecord>
            <Data>
               <Reference>PropertyOwnership</Reference>
               <WhereCondition>[PropertyName]=[PropertyNameTemp]</WhereCondition>
            </Data>
            <Statements>
               <Action Name="SetLocalVar">
                  <Argument Name="Name">RunningPercent</Argument>
                  <Argument Name="Value">[RunningPercent]+[PercentOwnership]</Argument>
               </Action>
            </Statements>
         </ForEachRecord>
         <ConditionalBlock>
            <If>
               <Condition>[RunningPercent]&gt;100</Condition>
               <Statements>
                  <Action Name="RaiseError">
                     <Argument Name="Number">1234</Argument>
                     <Argument Name="Description">Invalid OwnerShip</Argument>
                  </Action>
               </Statements>
            </If>
         </ConditionalBlock>
      </Statements>
   </DataMacro>
</DataMacros>
```

---

### For Each Record in

[image]